# kafka threads message from producer to consumer kafka topic

Tags: scala

It's Jasko here and I'm new in Kafka. I developed a "topic producer", as you can see it's a simple example. My aim is to send a JSON format message to the Customer. Then, I created a first JSON the next step is to convert it with a message. I build it as a project .jar format - but I can't test it because of Kerberos system. Probably there is something wrong with my code or configuration. I have a problem with testing it.**

package test

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerConfig, ProducerRecord}


object TestKafkaProducer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val broker = "your.web.host`enter code here`:9092"
    val topic = "testTopic"

    val props = new Properties()
    //which specifies a list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster**strong text**
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, broker)
    //default serialization and deserialization libraries for the record key-value pairs
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props

    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)

    // TODO pass json object 
    def sendMessages(): Unit = {
      println("Get Object json ")
      val message = "{\"schema\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":false},\"payload\":\"foo\"}"

      while (!message.isEmpty) {
      val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "1", message)
      producer.send(record)
      }

      producer.close()
    }

    }


}
```

Comment: What is the error stopping you ? Kerberose is a network authentication protocol which can be enabled to ensure secure communication with a Kafka cluster. Since your kafka cluster has Kerberose enabled, you will need the relevant information about the Kerberose config on your kafka cluster and provide it to the your producer.

Comment: thanks Sarvesh for answering me, but I do not know how to do with configurations how to pass information

Comment: Why are you not invoking the sendMessages method in your main?

Comment: thanks  Shankar,  you're right it would have been an error in the test phase